# Ajuda com API/useEffect - React

Tags: javascript, react, axios, promises, react-hooks

Preciso fazer uma chamada a API com React e pra isso estou usando o Axios.

Fazendo um teste com o código abaixo, no console eu consigo ver o resultado:

```
const [bill, setBill] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  api.post('/bills', { userId })
    .then(response => console.log(response.data))
    .catch(e => console.log(e));

console.log('bill', bill);
}, []);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, quando tento alimentar o estado com o código abaixo, o `console.log` do estado não altera, continua vazio.

```
const [bill, setBill] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  api.post('/bills', { userId })
    .then(response => {
      setBill(response.data);
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e));

  console.log('bill', bill);
}, []);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O estado está sendo provavelmente alterado sim. O problema é que você está executando o `console.log` antes dele ser alterado.

O processo de alteração de estado no React é assíncrono. Além disso, como você está trabalhando com uma chamada assíncrona (`api.post`), existe outra razão para esse estado estar sendo alterado de modo assíncrono.

Veja o código:

```js
api.post('/bills', { userId })
  .then(response => {
    setBill(response.data)
  })
  .catch(e => console.log(e));

console.log('bill', bill);
```

Ele é executado da seguinte forma:

1. Primeiro você executa a função `api.post`, que é assíncrona — está retornando uma [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).
2. Você executa o `console.log`, e `bill` ainda é um *array* vazio já que o estado não foi alterado.
3. A `Promise` é concluída, o que permite sucesso ou falha:

   - No caso de falha da `Promise`, o *callback* do `catch` é executado.
   - No caso da resolução sucedida da `Promise`, o *callback* do `then` é executado, o que define o estado.

Note que o estado está sendo definido *após* o `console.log`.

Para saber mais, procure entender o funcionamento das `Promise`s. Um bom artigo para começar: "[Promessas em JavaScript: uma introdução](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises?hl=pt-br)".