# React Hook não Aceita valor retornado de uma promise do Axios

Tags: array, typescript, axios, react-hooks

Como podem ver criei um estado chamado cur e dentro do map do array mat, estou fazendo uma requisição e quero adicionar a resposta dentro do evento. Mas quando dou console.log lá em baixo o estado aparece vazio (o setCur não funciona). Alguém sabe como resolver isso ?

ps: Criei um array global para testar e o array recebe os valores, porem quando tento passar o array para o estado, o estado permanece vazio.

```
export function CheckboxesDisciplinas({pessoa, options, ...props}: CheckboxesDisciplinasProps) {
  //var nomesDosCursos: Array<string> =  [];
  const [disciplinas, setDisciplinas] = useState<any[]>([]);
  const [cur, setCur] = useState<any[]>([],);
  const [disciplinasSelecionadas, setDisciplinasSelecionadas] = useState<any[]>([],);

  const classes = styles();
 
  useEffect(() => {

    if (pessoa) {
      ApiPessoa.findDisciplinasResponsavel(pessoa, options).then(({ data }) => {
        const mat = [... new Set(data.map(disc => disc.coddisciplina.toString().replace('/', '-')))]
        const unicas = [...new Set(data.map(disc => disc.coddisciplina))].map(
          coddisciplina => data.find(disc => disc.coddisciplina === coddisciplina),
        );

        setDisciplinas(unicas);

        mat.map(r => {
          Axios.get(`/pessoal/pessoa/${r}/buscarCursos`).then(response => {
            //nomesDosCursos.push(response.data.toString())
            setCur([...cur, response.data.toString()])
          })
        })

        if (props.initialValues) {
          const selecionadas = unicas.filter(disc =>
            props.initialValues!.some(coddisciplina => coddisciplina === disc.coddisciplina,),
          );

          setDisciplinasSelecionadas(selecionadas);
          props.onChange(selecionadas);
        }
      }); 

    } else {
      setDisciplinas([]);
      setDisciplinasSelecionadas([]);
      props.onChange([]);
    }
  }, [pessoa]);

  console.log(cur)   
  const isDisciplinaSelecionada = (disciplina): boolean => {
    return disciplinasSelecionadas.some(
      disc => disc.coddisciplina === disciplina.coddisciplina,
    );
  };
```

Comment: Veja se isso te ajuda! https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/460075/ajuda-com-api-useeffect-react

Comment: Edite a pergunta removendo a imagem e colando o código digitado, depois selecione o código e aperte Ctrl + K para formatá-lo.

Comment: prontinho @Evilmaax